# Sending images between 2 users using parse and sinch

Tags: java, android, button, parse-platform, sinch

I want to be able to send a picture from one user to another in a messaging app like on whatsApp, but I am not sure how to do that. I am using android and parse as my DB. I tried googling and nothing seems to help, I am new on Android development. I would prefer to use it as I do with my texts , since when sending messages between users I am using parse as my database. Can someone please assist, I am able to select the image from galery and load it in an image view but I am not sure how to send it as I would with text. The code that should be under when the button "send" is clicked.
    Below is the code that I have. Please have a look at it. I have been trying everything that I can think of but I am not getting anywhere.

```
   protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                //Everything Okay
                if (requestCode == LOAD_IMAGE_RESULTS) {
                    Uri pickedImage = data.getData();
                    InputStream inputStream;
                    try {
                        inputStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(pickedImage);
                        Bitmap selectImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
                        sendPicture.setImageBitmap(selectImage);

                        selectImage = ((BitmapDrawable) sendPicture.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
                        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                        selectImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 5, stream);
                        byte[] imageRec = stream.toByteArray();

                        final ParseObject imgMsgToBeSent = new ParseObject("SentImages");
                        final ParseFile fileRenamed;
                        //create parse file
                        fileRenamed = new ParseFile("SentImage.png", imageRec);

                        imgMsgToBeSent.put("receipientId", MessagingActivity.recipientId.toString());
                        imgMsgToBeSent.put("senderId", MessagingActivity.currentUserId.toString());
                        imgMsgToBeSent.put("imageReceived", fileRenamed);

                        sendImgBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                if (v.getId() == R.id.sendImageBtn) {
                                    messageService.sendMessage(MessagingActivity.recipientId.toString(), fileRenamed.toString());
                                    finish();
                                }
                            }
                        });

                    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "Unable to load image",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }

                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

### For Sharing Image after selected from Gallery ##

First get the image path and than send it via intent like this:

```
Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        Uri Imageuri = Uri.fromFile(new File(image));
        shareIntent.setType("image/");
        shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Imageuri);
 startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "ShareWia"));
```

for sharing image and text both just add one more settype and use put extra with text like this:

```
Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
             Uri Imageuri = Uri.fromFile(new File(image));
            shareIntent.setType("image/");
    shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, text);
            shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Imageuri);
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "ShareWia"));
```

Comment: This piece here gives me the screen to share it on the other platform, I want my end results to be sending the picture to the recipient in the same app of the message not sharing on other platform. Like a chat two people sending each other messages.  @santosh rawat

Answer (score 0):

Sinch does not support attachments in IM